# Uploading files inside WebApp without window explorer window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, angular4-forms

I want to use file upload option in my webapp, but while clicking on the upload button it is opening the explorer window. Instead I want to view and upload the file inside my website like now external windows all have to happen inside my webapp. Can someone help me with suggestions on this!

I added a photo to make it clear the second design is an usual one. I'm asking for the 1st design view.[image: sample design for image uploading]

Comment: Are you talking about drag and drop like like this https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/drag-drop-upload-1.gif ? 
You can't access your user's filesystem with html nor html5, the explorer's windows is the only way. If you really want it, you can use third party libraries like flash, silverlight or java.

Comment: "the file inside my website" is **already** uploaded. They **are** in your site.

Answer (score 0):

What ever plugin you use it will open an explorer window unless you drag and drop your files. Try following Jquery file upload it will allows you to handle both file select and drag and drop.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/